# How to check if push is currently disabled on OneSignal React Native SDK?

Tags: push-notification, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

OneSignal has a `OneSignal.disablePush(boolean)` method to toggle push notifications globally in app. How can I read the current value of it so that I can sync it with the app state?

In other words, I'm looking for a method like `OneSignal.isPushDisabled() : boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

The OneSignal React Native SDK includes the method `getDeviceState` which includes the `isPushDisabled` key in the response.

```
OneSignal.getDeviceState().then(deviceState => console.log(deviceState.isPushDisabled));
```